# JQuery counting child elements and modify CSS with an if statement

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to count the child elements of a div and modify the CSS with JS according to the outcome.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="images" class="images">
     <img id="imageItem" class="imageItem" src="http://www.foreclosurelistings.com/images/resources/los-angeles-ca/living-los-angeles.jpg" alt="Scrap image" />
     <img id="imageItem" class="imageItem" src="http://www.foreclosurelistings.com/images/resources/los-angeles-ca/living-los-angeles.jpg" alt="Scrap image" />
</div>
```

The JQuery:

```
count = $("#images img").length;
alert(count); //this alert has to be removed when if statement works
if (count == 2) {
   document.getElementById(imageItem).style.width = '200px';
}
```

When I display the outcome of the count variable with the alert box, it's correct, so the JQuery counts the child elements (the images inside the div images) correctly. But the if statement doesn't work.

What should my code look like to make this work?

Comment: ID's have to be unique, and `document.getElementById(imageItem)` needs quotes around imageItem

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using jQuery and plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

**id should be unique (remove it, you already have a class there)..use class**

**using jquery**

```
  var count = $("#images img.imageItem").length;

  if (count == 2) {
    $('.imageItem').css({width :'200px'});
  }
```

explanation

`$('.imageItem')` > selects element with class imageItem.. hence it selects both the image.
`.css({width :'200px'});` > adds Css properties to the selected element.. so this adds width to both the images.
and BANG!!!! see you have it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all define different image id

```
if (count == 2) {
    $('.imageItem').css('width', '200px');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

ok first idea is not to have 2 divs with same ID, buth rather with inteligent IDs

so I ASUME that u want to find out how much "imageItem" u have and ones u spread acroas some space

this is a wild guess so my sugestion is:

HTML:

```
<div id="images" class="images">
    <img id="imageItem_1" class="imageItem" src="" />
    <img id="imageItem_2" class="imageItem" src="" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
count = $("#images img").length;
alert(count);
for(var i=1, i<=count; i++) {
    $("#imageItem_" + i).css("width ", "200px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and time :) I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = $("#images img").length;
alert(count);
if (count == 2) {
   // document.getElementById(imageItem).style.width = '200px';
   $('.imageItem').width(200);
}
```

> One point here, do not use same id, ids should be unique for each element,

Comment: Thanks for letting me know and for the help I appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because only the first image will have the `width` because of the id conflict, so why don't you just loop through them like so

```
var images = $("#images img");

if( images.length === 2 ) {
    images.each(function(){
       this.style.width = '200px'
    });
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eXr2n/**